# java aggressive heap floating point exception

Tags: java

Hello I have been recently experimenting with kali linux 2.0 on my raspberry pi 3 . When I try running armitage I get the following error message

> Floating point exception

When I looked into the error more I found the shell file that runs. I decided to view the file and I found that -XX:+AgressiveHeap was causing the problem. So I tried running

> java -XX:AgressiveHeap

and I got the same exact error as I did when I ran armitage

Could someone please help I have already tried looking online on how to fix this error but I couldn't find anything. I am unsure what to do at this point. :(

Comment: That line is a JVM tuning parameter. I would suggest filing a bug report with the Kali maintainers or the armitage maintainers. This will give you some background https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4343/abeic/index.html. You may also be able to disable the option.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably figured this out already, to run Armitage on Raspberry Pi you need to edit /usr/share/armitage/armitage and remove the '-XX:AgressiveHeap' option in that file.

Alternately you can use this bash script to launch armitage:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/share/armitage/
java -XX:+UseParallelGC -jar armitage.jar $@
```